# I want to creating a java web service (SOAP), i need response some thing like this

Tags: java, soap

In this image there is main response Tag, enquiryResponse, here i need four main tags, TransactionID, responceCode, msisdn and subscriptions, and there values, in subscription case, subscription is main tag, then subscriptionDetails tag, in subscriptionDetails tags,
also see image.

How can i do this, can i use separate class for each main category , if yes then how can i get values from those classes, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.Depending on your requirement and appraoch.
Since you mentioned response. I am assuming that are trying to consume a webservice and have a contract(wsdl) you can use cxf or spring-ws client to consume the web service.Also you can use JAXB or jibx for marshalling/unmarshalling purpose.

Comment: I just want to make web service and provide wsdl, that return response like that,i am not a consumer, some one 'll consume my service , that's not my headache , in enquiryRequest() when some One consume my service , i have to assign those values to all these response param. Give me an example of some code how can i produce response like that i you can using Java, not any framework.

Comment: Quick search for "Create a contract first web service " will provide you loads of results. http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html e.g